# Is the forgetful functor from groups to monoids right adjoint?

Tags: category-theory

I am working on the construction of a group free over a monoid. Maybe you know where I can find something about the (right) adjointness of forgetful functor $U:\mathbf{Grp}\rightarrow\mathbf{Mon}$. I called it forgetful functor here, but it is clear to me that you could also look at it as an inclusion functor.

It *is* (right) adjoint isn't it? If not then I am working in vain. I do not exclude the possibility that this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adjoint is ambiguous. Left or right adjoint? In the case of $U : \mathsf{Grp} \to \mathsf{Mon}$, we have a left *and* a right adjoint (this is quite rare for forgetful functors). The right adjoint maps a monoid to its group of units. The left adjoint "adjoins" inverses to a monoid in order to obtain a group. It is (at least in the commutative case) known as the Grothendieck construction. If $M$ is given as a monoid by generators $X$ and relations $R$, then the Grothendieck group $G(M)$ is given by the same generators $X$ and relations $R$, but now as a group. For example, $\mathbb{N}$ is the free monoid on one generator, hence $G(\mathbb{N})$ is the free group on one generator, i.e. $G(\mathbb{N})=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Do you happen to know of there exists a similar construction for categories (gneeralized monoids) and groupoids (generalized groups)?

Comment: I was talking about right-adjoint and will make an edit to make that clear. Is there a place where this construction is exposed @StefanHamcke? However do not feel obliged to search for it.

Comment: Yes, $\mathsf{Gpd} \to \mathsf{Cat}$ has a right adjoint, it maps a category to its *core*: This is the subcategory containing all the isomorphisms of the given category. It also has a left adjoint, the localization at all morphisms. In order not to run into set-theoretical troubles, one has to work with small categories and groupoids here.

Comment: You write: 'The left adjoint "adjoins" inverses to a monoid in order to obtain a group.' Sounds pretty cool, but how can this be possible if the monoid doesn't satisfy the (two-sided) cancellation law?

Comment: It is always possible, by abstract reasons. If you have no cancellation, the unit (the "inclusion" to the Grothendieck group) just won't be monic.