# When is a monoid contained in a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, monoid

As stated in the answer of [Is the forgetful functor from groups to monoids right adjoint?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605393/is-the-forgetful-functor-from-groups-to-monoids-right-adjoint) , the forgetful functor 
$U:\mathbf{Grp}\rightarrow\mathbf{Mon}$ has a left adjoint $G$, and Grothendieck's construction is involved.

Now, my intuition tells me that for a monoid $M$ the following holds:

> $M$ can be embedded in some group if and only if $M \longrightarrow G(M)$ is injective.

Is this true? Can we find a characterization of such monoids?

Comment: For commutative or finite monoids, cancellation is a sufficient condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statement is correct.  The universal property of $G(M)$ is that a homomorphism of monoids $M \to G$, where $G$ is a group, extends uniquely to a group homomorphism $G(M)\to G$ via the map $M\to G(M)$.

It follows that if there exists an injective homomorphism $M\to G$, then the map $M\to G(M)$ is injective.

It is well known that a commutative semigroup can be embedded in a group if and only if it is [cancellative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup), and furthermore that every finite cancellative semigroup is a group.

In general, being cancellative is obviously a necessary condition, but it is not sufficient (though I don't have a counterexample on hand).  It seems that two different equivalent sets of conditions were worked out by Malcev and Lambek.

Both are discussed in [this 1971 paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1971-157-00/S0002-9947-1971-0281814-4/) of Bush, but this seems quite involved, and a more detailed discussion probably belongs on mathoverflow.

Comment: "It is well known... embedded if and only if cancellative ... being cancellative is obviously a necc. condition but it is not sufficient."  - These statements are in contradiction with one another.  Please advise us.

Comment: @PenAndPaperMathematics You are advised that not every semigroup is commutative.  For commutative semigroups, cancellative implies embeddable in a group.  For non-commutative, the situation is more complicated.